# Java Radio Button Submission

Tags: java, swing

how do you see if a button is selected or not and use it as a binary value

i have 3 radio buttons `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, they are all separate (not in a `ButtonGroup`), i need that when the user hits submit i can save the binary value (true if pressed, false if not pressed) into a variable

```
//Gets details when submit is pressed
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String name = t.getText();
        String surname = t1.getText();
        String studentID = t2.getText();
        //Code to place binary values into variables depending on the radio buttons selected
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are talking about a web app, you should post your HTML snippet

Comment: @SJuan76, he is not.  Java has its own RadioButtons and what not.

Comment: @kurtzbot well, look what tags he used.

Comment: @M.M., I think he meant the Java version of radio-buttons and submit.  He is certainly not asking for HTML suggestions because the code he pasted is purely Java.  The part about assigning an ActionListener to a submit button is because he is using the Java Swing/AWT Library.  That is certainly not HTML.  The problem is that the radio-button tag is specific to HTML radio-buttons, when Matthew wants Java radio-buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about a `JRadioButton`, you can use the `isSelected()` method to know whether the user checked it or not.

```
String name = t.getText();
String surname = t1.getText();
String studentID = t2.getText();
boolean checked = myRadioButton.isSelected();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean button1 = b1.isSelected();
boolean button2 = b2.isSelected();
boolean button3 = b3.isSelected();
```